# find html tag number with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 select tag.this is html code.

```
<div id="dropdownselect">
<select>
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>
<select>
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>
<select>
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

i create a jquery function when one of the select tag changed jQuery function must return the number of the select that changed.for example when The second select tag changed jquery function must return 2.

```
$("#dropdownselect select").on("change",function(){

});
```

what i should do to find Which one select tag changed??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function:

```
$("#dropdownselect select").on("change",function(){
    console.log($(this).index()+1);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/F28sF/)**

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is
>   an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
>   jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm looking at this too simple, but why don't you use data elements, like:

```
<div id="dropdownselect">
<select data-num="1">
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>
<select  data-num="2">
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>
<select  data-num="3">
<option>option1</option>
<option>option2</option>
</select>
</div>

$("#dropdownselect select").on("change",function(){
console.log($(this).data("num"));
});
```